# Изменение теней

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я делаю игру и хочу сделать изменение теней(типа через скрипт тип теней изменялся на Hard shadows вместо soft shadows), я смотрел на официальном форуме юнити но нечего не нашёл, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] private Light _light;

private void Start()
{
    _light.shadows = LightShadows.Hard;
    //_light.shadows = LightShadows.Soft;
    //_light.shadows = LightShadows.None;
}
```

Через инспектор для `_light` можно выбрать любой источник света.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помог